# Load resource file like (sql, txt etc) with absolute path to Spring ApplicationContext classpath

Tags: java, spring

Usually in a maven based spring application, if I need to make use of any file resource I would usually place it in a folder src/main/resources and then it would magically be available for spring app config file as shown below with a file reference such as "classpath:create-table.sql".

**spring_config.xml**

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="DERBY">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:create-table.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

It is even more magical if the application context is being loaded from web.xml with WebApplicationContext in which case it won't even need the following style of initialization for application context, but if I were to write a standalone java based spring application, which needs the following app context initialization and not maven or web based, how do I make any resource file available in it's classpath to refer such a file(create-table.sql) as shown above from with in config file?

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring_config.xml");
```

I know how to load with an absolute path such as shown below but what I need is to be able to make resource file available in classpath for the spring config file to refer from classpath itself.

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="DERBY">
    <jdbc:script location="file:C:\junit_framework\springmodulecontext\create-table.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

All the more better if there is a way to refer the file with a relative path, so that I could just place the resource file right next to config file and refer it with a current directory notation such as "file:./create-table.sql"? I tried this absolute notation but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You've lost me... Do you have an example of what you tried exactly but didn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

*if I were to write a standalone java based spring application and not maven or web based, I make any resource file available in classpath* by including its directory path (absolute or relative) to java -classpath list.

That is to say, if I want a file reference such as "classpath:create-table.sql" to actually read ./create-table.sql, I need to put a **.** (which is directory path of a desired file) to classpath like:

java -classpath .:lib/*.jar:...